# How to make an Angular Material table responsive

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, material-design-lite

I have a simple table with numerous columns, and I would like the columns to shrink automatically when sizing the browser window.  The `table-responsive` works with Bootstrap, but I am looking for something similar for Angular Material.  I am trying to avoid having 2 table definitions, and do not really want to do this myself in CSS.  Is there a standard way in Angular Material for this?

```
<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp" flex>
    <thead>
        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Date</th>
        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Time</th>
        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Park</th>
        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Home Team</th>
        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Away Team</th>
        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Win/Loss</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="game in games">
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{game.GameDate | SLS_Date}}</td>
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{game.GameTime | SLS_Time:'HH:mm' }}</td>
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{game.VenueName}}</td>
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{game.HomeTeamName}}</td>
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{game.AwayTeamName}}</td>
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{game.WinLoss}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note, I have used the Material Design Lite table here, as Angular Material does not have a table today.  Same problem, including the use of flex and grids.

I guess the new Material world does not like tables, so best option is to change the layout to not use tables.

Comment: Those who are interested in a solution for Angular 2+ can add a thumbs up to https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8494 because when more people show interest, the team will have more reason to prioritize this feature.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I created a little directive which can be applied to a `mat-table` table to make it responsive. This way it is easy to only add responsive behavior to some tables in the application (which was a requirement in my case).

[Angular 17 (TS strict mode)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/h3rzjs?embed=1&file=src%2Fexample%2Fmat-table-responsive%2Fmat-table-responsive.directive.ts)

[Angular 12+ (TS strict mode)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-table-responsive-strict-mode?file=src/app/mat-table-responsive/mat-table-responsive.directive.ts)

[Angular 12 (without TS strict mode)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-table-responsive?file=src/app/mat-table-responsive/mat-table-responsive.directive.ts)

So basically the directive duplicates the content of each header cell (column name) as a data attribute so it can be accessed via the CSS `content` property (inspired by this [article](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/)). Unfortunately CSS styles can't be applied to a directive, so the styles need to be imported globally.

**Features**

- no extra hard coded column names for mobile view
- reacts on language changes and updates the column names for mobile view
- reacts also on row changes/updates (e.g. add a row)
- in mobile view it only shows the columns which were made sortable via the `matSort` directive

This should not be seen as a general solution, as it does of course not cover all use cases. Also the styling of the table mobile view is bound to my specific requirements and probably needs to be adjusted. But i just wanted to share it, so that it maybe could serve and help as a starting point for others.

Comment: Awesome job! Thanks

Comment: wow. Just awesome. Thanks for the wonderful solution. You just save the world. I really mean it.

Comment: Yes, he really saved.

Thanks very much, @knoefel
Maybe deploy the directive as an angular package so that anyone can use it without creating the directive in their code

Comment: I'm having problem consuming this directive in Angular 12. It complain related to this `Type 'HTMLCollection' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.`.

Comment: @klaydze I updated the stackblitz demo to Angular 12 and it's still working fine. I think your `tsconfig.json` is missing the `DOM.Iterable` lib. I added it also in the stackblitz demo, so you can check there how to use it.

Comment: @knoefel thank you updating. since I have `strict: true` in `tsconfig`, it also complaining `Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<[boolean, boolean], (HTMLTableRowElement | HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLTableRowElement> | null)[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<[boolean, boolean], [HTMLTableRowElement, HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLTableRowElement>]>'.
Type '(HTMLTableRowElement | HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLTableRowElement> | null)[]' is not assignable to type '[HTMLTableRowElement, HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLTableRowElement>]'. Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.ts(2345)`

Comment: @klaydze I made an alternative version using the TS config setting `"strict": true` -> [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-table-responsive-strict-mode?file=src/app/mat-table-responsive/mat-table-responsive.directive.ts) I had to add `"strictPropertyInitialization": false` in `tsconfig.json` so please check that file too.

Comment: @knoefel error in `mapTo`. TS2345: Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<[boolean, boolean], (HTMLTableRowElement | HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLTableRowElement> | null)[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<[boolean, boolean], [HTMLTableRowElement, HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLTableRowElement>]>'.
  Type '(HTMLTableRowElement | HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLTableRowElement> | null)[]' is not assignable to type '[HTMLTableRowElement, HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLTableRowElement>]'.
    Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.
54 mapTo([this.thead.rows.item(1), this.tbody.rows]),

Comment: Did you use the updated code in `mat-table-responsive.directive.ts` from the new stackblitz demo i linked in my previous comment? Because your error shows that you use the version without strict mode: check the last line in your last comment `54 mapTo([this.thead.rows.item(1), this.tbody.rows])`.

Comment: @knoefel wow! this fixed everything! thank you it's a very nice directive!

Comment: Changed my acceptance to this more popular answer, as it does provide the basics that I need. The old answer was that it was not supported by MDL with a GitHub issue pending.  This coded answer goes well beyond what I expected as result, and the work alone deserves the credit, plus it does work for my use case.

Comment: line: `columnNames: [...headRow.children].map(` error: `Type 'HTMLCollection' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.` **:'(**  Line: `rows: [...bodyRows].map(row => [...row.children])` Error: `Type 'HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLTableRowElement> | undefined' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.`. I'm using angular 13

Comment: @ManuelVillarroel you need to add the `"DOM.Iterable"` lib in `tsconfig.json`. Check the stackblitz demos, there you can find how to add it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57621104/type-htmlcollectionofhtmlcanvaselement-must-have-a-symbol-iterator-met) is also a stack overflow question regarding this subject.

Comment: This is an extremely elegant solution, thank you for this!

Comment: Just noticed that the header `<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>` is staying in the old state, it doesn't transforming on mobiles.

Comment: Ok, I got the problem: Eslint requires to add the "app" prefix to the directive `selector: '[matTableResponsive]'` and I did it. Once I removed this, it's working as a charm now!

Comment: Tried to use this with angular 16, doesn't working atm. anyone can point me why?

Comment: Hey @LeandroMenezes, I've added a StackBlitz example using Angular 17. The main problem was that they changed the names of the CSS classes for the `mat-table` component, which the directive uses to style the mobile view.

Comment: there was so many things I was not aware when I tried your code for the first time lol. Thanks so much! It's working now

Comment: @knoefel mapTo is deprecated in newer versions of rxjs so we can use map(() => ()) instead. Should look like this: 

map(() => ({ headRow: this.thead.rows.item(0)!, bodyRows: this.tbody.rows })),

Comment: @knoefel Looks like the `this.thead = this.table.nativeElement.querySelector('thead');` and `this.tbody = this.table.nativeElement.querySelector('tbody');` are not reliable inside the ngOnInit because it's possible for it to be called before the mat-table fully initializes.  I'm looking at workarounds for this.  Currently, the suggested solution I found was to use a bound subject. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347334/angular-4-how-to-run-a-directive-method-only-after-its-parent-has-fully-render

Comment: Moving it to the ngAfterViewInit might be a valid solution too.

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no way you can achieve this in MDL, Check out [this](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1504) issue on github.

I am having the same problem with my tables, but I guess I will have to make them responsive my self. There are a lot of tutorials out there & you should do a bit of research which table design would suit your responsive website the best.

Also, I think its worth checking out materializecss's [responsive tables](http://materializecss.com/table.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have come to the same conclusion and moved to the Angular Grid instead.  I also did some redesign to not need the tables the same way.  The Materialize CSS is a nice thought to get somethings to work.

Comment: I love Materialize as the defacto css framework for Material specification, but unfortunately, they never changed their grid and layout to use flexbox instead of floats. Not to mention that the project is dead; no commits in years, I believe

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution is to wrap your table with a `<div>` with following styles:

```
width: 100%;
overflow-x: auto;
```

Comment: This isn't really a profound solution, but in regards to the complexity of other solutions, this is an elegant and viable solution for me. Thanks.

Comment: It worked like a charm for both regular `table` and `mat-table`. Note though, that it doesn't have to be necessarily a `div` element; it works for `mat-card-content` too.

Answer (score 0):

This directive doesn't work for Angular Material 16.2.12 / Angular 16 (maybe other post - 12 versions as well).

In the links
Angular 12 (without TS strict mode)
and
Angular 12+ (TS strict mode)

Angular Material ^12.2.1. is used. If you open the inspector for Stackblitz demo in mobile view you see that generated classes are `.mat-table`, `.mat-header-row`, `.mat-header-cell` and so on. These classnames changed in Angular Material 16.2.12 to `.mat-mdc-table`, `.mat-mdc-header-row` and `.mat-mdc-header-cell` respectively.

Changing the classnames in mat-table-responsive.directive.scss should fix this.

Kudos to Knoefel for creating this directive!