# Type 'HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLCanvasElement>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: typescript, iterator, iteration, for-of-loop

I am building an Array with

`const myCanvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')`

that it's actually working. It returns me something like this:

```
images: [
  0: canvas,
  1: canvas,
  2: canvas
]
```

This is for a TypeScript project, I want to iterate this Array and transform each image in order to log it.

Like this:

```
for (const image of myCanvas) {
  console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
}
```

(I am not using `foreach` because it doesn't works with `HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLCanvasElement>` type)

I need to iterate the `HTMLCollection` that `getElementsByTagName` is returning me. The output is:

```
Type 'HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLCanvasElement>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator
```

[image: error]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76512245/14344959

Answer (score 38):

In order to iterate that way you need to set `compilerOptions` like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
        // ...
        "target": "ES6",
        "lib": [
            "DOM",
            "DOM.Iterable",
            "ES6"
        ]
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: If using VS Code, you may need to restart the IDE for the settings to take effect.

Comment: Thanks I also had to restart my live build listener `wp-scripts` you can also replace ES6 with `esnext`

Comment: "dom.iterable" fixed that for me

Answer (score 16):

I've got this in my tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  // ...
  "target": "es2015",
  "module": "es2020",
  "lib": [
    "es2018",
    "dom"
  ]
  // ...
}
```

I add `dom.Iterable` to `lib` and output is gone. Now it look like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  // ...
  "target": "es2015",
  "module": "es2020",
  "lib": [
    "es2018",
    "dom",
    "dom.Iterable"
  ]
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It may be worth checking your TypeScript / definitions version, [because I get no errors](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwMIEMwDcUQFwwBIAqAsgDJIgA2FApsFAJbgDyAZgDyGmoZYCiNcamCgA+GAF4YAExDAAroOEA6AObUo-aoqgQAQggIoVAORSCAFAHJgaTBEsBKANwBYAFDuWIAE4xzoSFh6OCNqGBAWeGRbLAcYAG93GGSYAIhKaiUKEBVzYNClKBAAERQoFABVACUScwdndwBfd08fPxogiRgABicYehg2KO47LKEVKAALPvoAalm4xLdktIysnPNEEawAbXoAXUKSssqauoa3RqA). I believe the errors relate to some older browsers actually not supporting iteration of the HTML collection, so you *could* use a traditional for loop.

Both examples shown below:

```
const myCanvas: HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLCanvasElement> = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');

for (const image of myCanvas) {
  console.log(image.toDataURL());
}

for (let i = 0; i < myCanvas.length; i++) {
  console.log(myCanvas[i].toDataURL());
}
```

Comment: Well, now it is working, actually it was working before as well but with the compiler error. I don't think that it depends of the browser because I am using chrome. Thank you Fenton!

Answer (score 2):

I face almost same as but Type is different. here element type is `HTMLElement` see below error message which one I faced.

**-> Error Message**

> Type 'HTMLCollection' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator

**-> Solution**

for solve this error we can use `Array.from(elem)` method. its Creates an array from an iterable object.

```
const currentElement = event.target as HTMLElement;
const index = Array.from(currentElement.children).indexOf(this.dropPlaceholder);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use for-of like this:

```
const menus = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-menu');
for (const menusKey of Object.keys(menus)) {
  console.log(menus[menusKey]);
}
```